# I would like to know of some resources that relate Identity theft and computers

Tags: security, anti-theft

This is for an english project, which is how identity fraud and computers are related. I need a few sources by Thursday, and I can only have one internet source (not wikipedia, online encyclopedias and news paper articles don't count as an online source). I was wondering if there is anywhere that goes over different viruses (trojans, etc) and how they could potentially steal your identity? Basically anything that ties identity theft and computers together, like a security book. I am sorry for the vague question, if I knew how to answer it I wouldn

Comment: This is outside the scope of SuperUser, please refer to the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq). You might want to look at the [IT Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) SE site. They do address identity theft and social engineering but you'll probably need to ask specific questions rather than request general overviews.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google of [How does identity theft happen?](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=How+does+identity+theft+happen%3F) reveals this article: [Identity Theft and Your Credit Report](http://www.creditreport.com/identitytheft/facts/how-id-theft-happens.aspx)

Comment: http://www.fbi.gov/about-us/investigate/cyber/identity_theft . . . http://www.ftc.gov/bcp/edu/microsites/idtheft/ . . . http://www.cybercrime.gov/ Some have said that much of the IDtheft that occurs had little to do with computers :-) and a lot to do with humans giving out info. Ok so they did it with thier e-mail:-) but they would have done it on the phone or in person also.